# std::array template function

Tags: c++, templates, std

I have a simple function to shuffle elements in an std::array

```cpp
template <typename T, uint size>
void Shuffle(std::array<T, size> &arr) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        std::swap(arr[i], arr[Random(i, arr.size())]);
    }
}
```

make/g++ doesn't like the way I'm declaring this, giving the error "variable or field Shuffle declared void." From what I've found, this is probably an irrelevant error message, but I can't figure out what's actually wrong here.

Comment: Is `uint` a defined type? Did you try replacing it with `std::size_t`?

Comment: The code will also have a problem when an empty array is passed. Since i is unsigned, `arr.size() - 1` will underflow and will lead to a very long loop and invalid array access. Consider writing `i + 1 < arr.size()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uint` doesn't match the type of the 2nd template parameter of [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), which is `std::size_t`. This causes template argument deduction failing when calling `Shuffle`, unless you specify template arguments explicitly.

You should declare the 2nd template parameter with type `std::size_t`. e.g.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t size>
void Shuffle(std::array<T, size> &arr)
```